# How to prove the formula of the average of linear search algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I'm reading a book in data structure. The author states the following

> **Linear Search:**
>
> ...
>   Also, assuming that each name in the file is equally likely to be
>   picked, it is intuitively clear that the average number of comparisons
>   for a file with $n$ records is equal to $n/2$.

Now let's say we have a list of elements $[1, 2, \cdots, n]$, to compute its average with the equally likely assumption (*i.e.* the probability of each element is $1/n$), hence 
$$
E(x) = 1\frac{1}{n} + 2\frac{1}{n} + \cdots + n\frac{1}{n} = \frac{n+1}{2} 
$$

My question is why in the book the average number of comparisons is $n/2$?

Comment: If instead of averages you think of the median of a data sample, then *by definition* half the data points lie below the median, and half lie above it.

Comment: @avs, it is true but this is the median not the average which is the word that is used by the author.

Comment: What kind of search is this exactly? Number of comparisons in what sense? What is the algorithm doing?

Comment: @ArukaJ, it is linear search stated in the quote. It is an algorithm for searching whether a given element is in the list or not.

Comment: @CroCo, yes, but the word "average" is applied by the author to the number of comparisons, not to the set of values in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it is $(n+1)/2$. It's possible the book was being imprecise for the sake of generally saying that it'll take roughly half of $n$ on average.

Comment: In cases like this, we often only care about behavior as $n$ gets large, so the constant gets lost.  You will probably soon see [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), where you only care about the leading term.

Comment: @RossMillikan You are probably right; the only reason I didn't mention Big O is because the division by $2$ would drop out as well

Comment: There are two levels here. The $+\frac 12$ is very small compared to $\frac n2$. The Big O approach is coarser than that. You are correct that it doesn't care about the factor $\frac 12$, which doesn't seem so bad, but suppose it were $10^{12}$

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the name is somewhere in the list (of distinct names), then you don't have to do the last comparison—once you've ruled out the first $(n-1)$ slots, you know the name is in the last slot. So the sum only goes up to $n-1$, and the result is indeed $n/2$.